# V8 compiler errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, v8, embedded-v8

I recently managed to generate the visual studio project file for V8, but it doesn't compile

When I compile the `All` solution it spends maybe ~10 minutes compiling and then presents me with a bunch of error (at least in Release mode, 35 to be exact).

Example:

```
MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. js2c
C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\..\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\experimental-libraries.cc': No such file or directory v8_nosnapshot
C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\..\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\extras-libraries.cc': No such file or directory   v8_nosnapshot   
C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\..\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\libraries.cc': No such file or directory  v8_nosnapshot
C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\..\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\experimental-extras-libraries.cc': No such file or directory  v8_nosnapshot
```

Why isn't it compiling correctly?

Comment: I have no experience with this project, but it sounds like there's files listed in your project that aren't actually in the source files you are trying to compile. As to WHY that is, would probably be that you are compiling a different version than the project file is for, or something similar...

Comment: don't build "all", build "native" if that's available.  I've never built V8 on windows, though.  but "all" on linux can cause problems.

Comment: @xaxxon There is no "native" option that I see. And none of them compile successfully.

Comment: ah, that stinks.   do those files actually exist?

Comment: @xaxxon They don't appear to. But I don't get why it's searching for source files in an obj folder. The only obj folder contains obj files.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't find the directory `v8_nosnapshot`

What are your project settings? If you have access to this you might want to check that paths to your source and header files resolve correctly.

Else place the `v8_nosnapshot` directory and other source files needed for a successful compile where the compiler can find it

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the js2c project -> Properties, Under VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories, Check if the python and cygwin directories are set properly.

The python directory should exists under `v8\third_party` as shown below. If not, you can copy the python folder under depot_tools to `v8\thrid_party\python_**` and compile. You can also expand the macro and see what is the value for `MSBuildProjectDirectory`:

```
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\thrid_party\python_26
```